# Not able to make html elements visible using Jquery in twitter Boostrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had made the input text button invisible using:

```
#blog_name {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And my jquery:

```
$('img#wp').click(function() {
  $('input#blog_name').show(); //show  
});
```

Comment: try using only display:none; i think show() doesnt work well with visibility: hidden;

Comment: You should put a snippet of code into jsfiddle.net or post more. The only thing I could suggest is to get rid of the css you have there and add the hide class bootstrap provides.

Comment: show() doesn't work with visiblity, only the display property.

Comment: In bootstrap you have visible and hidden classes, use those instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have `visibility: hidden` in your css, jQuery will change `display: none` to `display: block` but not the visibility. So it is still hidden.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/YXUVE/